# Java doesn't see space in string

Tags: java, string, split, char

So, I'm trying to parse some text file which has multiple lines of text. My job is to go through all words and print them out in file.

So, I read all lines, I'm looping through them and splitting every line by spaces, like this:

`line.split("\\s+");`

Now, the problem is that in some cases Java does not see space between two words...

I was also trying to loop through string which has space but Java doesn't see it, and `Character.isSpaceChar(char)` returned true...

And now I'm completly confused...

Here is code:

```
public void createMap(String inputPath, String outputPath)
            throws IOException {
                File f = new File(inputPath);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outputPath);
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath(),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        for (String l : lines) {
            for (String w : l.split("\\s+")) {
                if (isNotRubbish(w.trim())) {
                    fw.write(w.trim() + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
        fw.close();
    }
private boolean isNotRubbish(String w) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@?\\p{L}+",
                Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(w);
        return m.matches();
    }
```

Comment: Can you give a reproducable example for those _some cases_ ?

Comment: So, maybe it's not ASCII spaces. But impossible to say since you provide little in the way of actionable details.

Comment: Of course... I forgot about giving an example

`Beogradu u fajlu Štaba vrhovne komande ( JVUO ) pod oznakom K`

There, "u fajlu" and "oznakom K" is not separated, but everything other is

Comment: Without seeing an actual copied/pasted sample of the data, and the code around the `line.split()`, it is unlikely anybody can help you.

Comment: @mister11: [that's not what I'm getting](https://ideone.com/DMKDyW).

Comment: Have you googled for tokenizing strings using spaces?

Comment: From your example, `line.split("\\s+")` returns `[Beogradu, u, fajlu, Štaba, vrhovne, komande, (, JVUO, ), pod, oznakom, K]`. So it works fine. Note that I copy-pasted your "not working" string.

Comment: Print the integer values of each character to determine what those space characters actually are

Comment: That's just odd... I c/p my example to the dummy project and it's working... But still, when I try to do the same thing in my main project, it does not work...

I added code above... Is there maybe a problem with reading a file?

@m0skit0 how? that method does work with string provided and return if it is a word or not

Comment: @mister11 use a debugger and set breakpoints, or add print statements, to see what the values are at different points in the program.

Comment: So, if I take only a piece of whole line (piece which contains text that is not split in original program) and try to split it, it works... But if I take whole line

`[Dokument se nalazi u Arhivu vojnoistorijskog instituta u Beogradu u fajlu Štaba vrhovne komande ( JVUO ) pod oznakom K - 12 , 30/12 .]`

then it fails to split same thing

Now I see that somehow some spaces are not really spaces but unprintable ASCII characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have in your text character which is similar to [non-breakable-space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) which is not white space so it can't be matched via `\\s`.

In that case try to use `\p{Zs}` instead of `\s`.

As mentioned in http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

> `\p{Zs}` will match any kind of space character

BTW if you would also like to include other separators than spaces like tabulators `\t` or line breaks `\r` `\n` you can combine `\p{Zs}` with `\s` like `[\p{Zs}\s]`

Comment: Well, now I have another problem then... How to split string by spaces or by non-printable ASCII

Comment: Thanks man... I can vote you up because of my reputation :)