# Encoding issue regex

Tags: java, regex, encoding

I have the following regex:

```
^[0-9a-z]+\.[ ]+(table of )?contents
```

The purpose is to match strings such as:
"b. table of contents"

I am using PDFBox to parse pdf documents and I go line by line looking for the above mentioned string. Interestingly enough, when the doc finds a string with exactly "b. table of contents", the string fails to match the regex.

Now I tested by typing the exact same string manually on an online regex tester and I got a match:
[image]

When I try copy pasting the parsed text that looks exactly as the string I typed, I do not get a match:
[image]

And FYI, those are single spaces, no tabs. Upon further inspection and after comparing the two strings, it seems the string from the parser has some weird character being represented as an empty space that looks as follows:

```
b.† table†of†contents
```

But on a notepad it just looks like:

```
b.† table†of†contents
```

I have to guess this is an encoding issue or something similar to that, but if I try to write a regex to account for that weird character, there is still no match:
[image]

This is the regex that I have tried:

```
^[0-9a-z]+\.[ †]+(table[ †]+of[ †]+)?contents
```

So is there anyway to account for this um encoding so the regex can pick it up?
If anyone is interested, I am using the String 'matches' method to match the string with the regex in my code.

**UPDATE:**
Please see comment below for link to regex and string.

Comment: You can view the regex and the string here: https://regex101.com/r/ufE1xd/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you copy-paste line on which you are applying regex and print characters it contains like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("b.  table of contents".chars().toArray()));
```

you will see as result:

```
[98, 46, 160, 32, 116, 97, 98, 108, 101, 32, 111, 102, 32, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 115]
//       ^^^
```

`160` is index of [No-Break Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=160) which isn't matched by simple space indexed as 32 which causes your regex to fail.

To solve it replace `†` symbol with that whitespace  like `^[0-9a-z]+\.[  ]+(table[  ]+of[  ]+)?contents`.

OR for more general solution visit [Java doesn't see space in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585683/java-doesnt-see-space-in-string)