# Removing spaces from a String in Java

Tags: java, string

**Solved**, thanks to [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo).
The problem was that the String contained a no break space, which can be removed with:

```
val = val.replaceAll("[\\s\\u00A0]", "");
```

Allright, I am faced with a weird problem, and I just can't figure it out - or maybe the error is obvious, and I'm just plain stupid.

I am working on a Java web application, where the user will enter a numbered value through a textbox.
I want the user to be able to enter "100 000", so naturally I'll have to collect the value as a String object, remove all spaces, and parse it as an int.

However, the spaces in the String aren't removed as expected. Does anyone have any insights on why this code isn't working?

I've already tried all of these;

```
val = val.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
val = val.replaceAll("\\s", "");
val = val.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

The code currently looks like this:

```
if(value == 0) {
    String val = request.getParameter("value");
    if(val != null) {
        val = val.replaceAll("\\s", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(val);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Returning JSON with error;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
It does work if I don't fetch the String from the request, and just initialize it to "100 000". Could it be something related to the browser charset?

I also can't provide anymore code - this happens directly inside the javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#doPost

```
String value = "100 000" // This works!
```

I expect the output to not have any remaining spaces, but the actual output is still contain spaces, e.g. "100 000"

Comment: Not able to reproduce this behavior. Works fine for me.

Comment: `val = val.replaceAll("\\s+", "");` is correct and enough. If this does not work then the value is changed elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, normally this should work.. I've updated the post with more details.

Comment: @forpas The value isn't changed elsewhere, please see my provided code example

Comment: Print characters identifiers to know what you received. You can use something like `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(val.chars().toArray()))`. My guess is that it doesn't contain simple space but maybe [No-Break Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/).

Comment: ```System.out.println(Arrays.toString(val.chars().toArray()))``` prints out [49, 48, 48, 160, 48, 48, 48] when val = "100 000". The space has a value of 160

Comment: Which confirms my suspicion about No-Break Space which as hexadecimal value is represented as `00A0` which as decimal `a(hex)*16(dec)=10(dec)*16(dec)=160(dec)`. Now question is why it appears there. Did you perhaps copy-pasted that `100 000` from somewhere (document, pdf, some site) or was each character typed on keyboard?

Comment: `val = val.replaceAll("[\\s\\u00A0]+$", "");` shouldn't contain `$` which represents end of string. Because of it you would be able to only remove spaces at the end.

Comment: Didn't even notice this. The problem does not occur when I type from the keyboard, only when the values in the text box are pre-populated from the server.

Comment: Probably duplicate of [Java doesn't see space in string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22585683).

Comment: Your update to the regex solved it, updated the post. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

```
String sss = "100 000";
    sss = sss.replaceAll(" ", "");
    System.out.println (sss);
    int x = Integer.parseInt(sss);
    System.out.println(x);
```

This worked just fine , you have a problem somewhere else .

if you can show us more of the code we might be able to help more .

Comment: Please see my updated question - this works for me too.
The problem occurs when I fetch the string from the HttpServletRequest object.

Comment: The problem is surly with the , request.getParameter("value")
it turned out that the problem is whiter from the getParameter method , or its value . 
try to print the value and check it before you do anything

Comment: It may be, but that is the method from the javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet....

Comment: I mean there must be wrong with your implementation or the $.ajax setup 
this might help throw this .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568142/how-to-read-json-sent-by-ajax-in-servlet