# JFormattedTextField: the formatted text to numbers without spaces

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I've got a little problem with `JFormattedTextField`: I want to hold and retrieve numbers from 1000 to 65535. But when I retriev value (7000) from `JFormattedTextField`, it have one space like  7 000, and when I parse value to `Integer` `(Integer.parseInt(formattedTextField.getText()))`, it fail.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7 000"
```

If I do this with `MaskFormatter()` and `.setMask("#####")` it's ok, but I want to do this with `NumberFormatter()`.

How can I setup `JFormattedTextField` without an additon space?

```
    NumberFormatter nfsoc   = new NumberFormatter();
    nfsoc.setMaximum(Short.MAX_VALUE*2 - 1);
    nfsoc.setMinimum(1);
    nfsoc.setAllowsInvalid(false);

    formattedTextField      = new JFormattedTextField(nfsoc);

    formattedTextField.setText("7000");      

    int socket              = Integer.parseInt(formattedTextField.getText()) 
    //java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7 000"
```

I expect the output of `Integer.parseInt(tfServerSocket.getText())` to be 7000, but the actual output is `//java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7 000"`

Comment: Do not use Integer.parseInt or getText().  Use [getValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#getValue%28%29) instead.  As in, `int socket = ((Number) formattedTextField.getValue()).intValue();`.  NumberFormatter uses a localized number format, while Integer.parseInt always expects the same format, consisting of only digits and an optional sign.

Comment: .getValue() - it's good solution, but some times it turn out NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585683/java-doesnt-see-space-in-string

Comment: Because [`JFormattedTextField.getValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#getValue()) return the last valid value, so if no valid value were inputted, ever. It returns null.

Comment: Note that you didn't set a `Locale` so you could get `.` or even `,` instead of a space like you current locale. Indeed, `new NumberFormatter()` will simply use `NumberFormat.getNumberFormat` which return a locale dependent format. See [Using Predefined Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of addition space:

```
NumberFormatter nfsoc   = new NumberFormatter();
NumberFormat nf         = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
nf.setGroupingUsed(false); // It removes any separator
nfsoc.setFormat(nf);
nfsoc.setMaximum(Short.MAX_VALUE*2 - 1);
nfsoc.setMinimum(1);
nfsoc.setAllowsInvalid(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to parse an integer.

- NumberFormatter uses a localized NumberFormat, which means it formats and parses according to your locale (country/region).
- Integer.parseInt doesn’t care about locale.  It always expects numbers in the same format used by Java source code, namely “[±]*ddd*…” (all ASCII digits, optionally preceded by a sign).

Use the [getValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#getValue%28%29) method of JFormattedTextField.  It exists specifically to do what you’re trying to do:  obtain the value of the JFormattedTextField.

It also has the advantage that it will allow your code to work in all locales, not just yours.  For instance, in the United States, your example value is written 7,000.  In Germany, it’s written 7.000.

```
Number socketValue = (Number) formattedTextField.getValue();
if (socketValue == null) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
        formattedTextField.getTopLevelAncestor(),
        "A valid port valid is required.",
        "Cannot create connection",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
}

int socket = socketValue.intValue();
```

Comment: 0


In my case I have a settings window. When I open it and fill (by background) all net settings, it is not nessasery to refill socket field. If I do not refill JFormattedTextField it (getValue()) returns null. What is why I have to use .getText().

Comment: If your JFormattedTextField is empty, passing the text to Integer.parseInt will fail anyway.  You don’t have to display a JOptionPane, but you will need to handle the possibility of the field having no value somehow.  The only actions I can think of are to either use a default value, or show an error.

Answer (score -2):

I've found out it not a space but special character `\p{Zs}`

tfServerSocket.getText().replaceAll("\p{Zs}", "") = 7000 // without any addition character!

Comment: Don’t do this.  You are replacing the work that NumberFormatter does.  And your code will not work in other locales.  Use `getValue()`;  it does all that work for you.